# Why is 5 larger? (comparing user inputs in a simple if statement)

Tags: python, if-statement

Beginner question here (sorry). I am practicing conditional statements comparing integer inputs. Oddly enough, when I put in "5" as my first input, I am told it is larger than "10" (my second input). I must be missing something because I've stared much too long and can't figure it out.

Code:

```
print("Enter first number")
first = input()
print("Enter second number")
second = input()

if first > second:
    print("Greatest is", first)
elif second > first:
    print("Greatest is", second)
else:
    print("Both are the same!")
```

Below are my inputs and the result:

```
Enter first number
5
Enter second number
10
Greatest is 5
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing a lexicographical comparison of strings (e.g. "a" < "b") instead of a numerical comparison of integers. Which programming language is this? Please add the programming language as a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Python, [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string and `"5"` is lexicographically larger than `"10"`.

You can use `int(...)` to convert a string into an integer:

```
first = int(input())
```